# find $h\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $\hat{h} = a(n)$ for all $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral

> Prove or disprove that for any $a\in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, there exists $h\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ so that $\hat{h}(n) = a(n)$ for all $n$, where $h : [-\pi,\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$ is $2\pi$-periodic, $ \lVert h\rVert_2 < \infty, \hat{h}(n) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{[-\pi, \pi]} h(\theta) e^{-in\theta} d\theta$.

Clearly taking $h(\theta) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a(n) e^{in\theta}$ doesn't work as this function might not even be defined (but if $(a(n))\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z}),$ the function would be defined and continuous). If I can show that $\hat{h}(n) = a(n)$ for all $n$, then $\lVert h\rVert_2 = \lVert a\rVert_{\ell^2} <\infty.$ But since $h$ may not always converge and may even take negative values, I'm not sure if I can just interchange the infinite sum and the integral to get the result I want.

Comment: Show that the sum defining $h(\theta)$ converges in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the following result:

**Theorem:**

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space and let $\{u_j\}_{j \in J}$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$, with $J$ being a non-empty set. Then, there exists a bijective linear map $\phi: V \to l^2(J)$ which preserves inner products.

**Proof:**

Define the map:
$$f \mapsto \{\langle f,u_j \rangle\}_{j \in J}$$
Observe that $\{\langle f,u_j \rangle\}_{j \in J}$ is square summable. Obviously, this map is linear and by the properties of orthonormal bases, it actually also preserves inner products. So, now it comees down to showing that it is is surjective and injective. Injectivity actually also follows from the properties of an orthonormal basis. Next, we show that for any function $f: J \to \mathbb{C}$ which is square summable, we have that:
$$\sum_{j \in J} f(j) u_j$$
converges in $V$. Observe that:
$$\left|\left|\sum_{j \in J} f(j) u_j \right|\right|^2 = \sum_{j \in J} |f(j)|^2 < \infty$$
Since the series above converges, it follows that there are, at most, countably many $j$'s with $f(j) \neq 0$. So, in fact, it's sufficient for us to just consider $f$ to be defined on the natural numbers. In that case, we'll prove that the sequence $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) u_k \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $V$. Let $m > n$. Then:
$$\left|\left|\sum_{k=1}^{m} f(k) u_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)u_k \right|\right|^2 = \left|\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} f(k) u_k \right|\right|^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} |f(k)|^2$$

As $m,n \to \infty$, that right-hand side goes to $0$. So, it follows that our given sequence is Cauchy in $V$ and, hence, convergent. $\Box$

Now, it follows that your proposed function:
$$h(\theta) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n) e^{in\theta}$$
does actually work.